# Почему библиотека openMP не подключается через QtCreator?

Tags: c, многопоточность, qtcreator, openmp

Проблема почему-то QtCreator не собирает программу с библиотекой openMP (работаю в ubuntu).

Что я делаю не так ??

Вот код :

**untopenm.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console fopenmp openmp
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lomp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
```

**main.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N = 2

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            printf("Thread %d i = %d\n",omp_get_thread_num(),i);
        }         
    }
}
```

А вот результат :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/untopenmp$ ./untopenmp 
Thread 0 i = 0
Thread 0 i = 1
Thread 0 i = 2
Thread 0 i = 3
Thread 0 i = 4
Thread 0 i = 5
Thread 0 i = 6
Thread 0 i = 7
Thread 0 i = 8
Thread 0 i = 9
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/untopenmp$ gcc -openmp main.c -o tread
/tmp/ccyRWXdi.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/untopenmp$ gcc -fopenmp main.c -o tread
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/untopenmp$ ./tread 
Thread 0 i = 0
Thread 0 i = 1
Thread 0 i = 2
Thread 0 i = 3
Thread 0 i = 4
Thread 1 i = 5
Thread 1 i = 6
Thread 1 i = 7
Thread 1 i = 8
Thread 1 i = 9
```

Как видите, программа собранная через командную строку отрабатывает.
А программа собранная в Qt увы нет ;_; (также она не выкидывает предупреждений)

---

**untopenm.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp

QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS += -fopenmp

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lomp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
```

Вот результат :

```
Thread 0 i = 0
Thread 0 i = 1
Thread 0 i = 2
Thread 0 i = 3
Thread 0 i = 4
Thread 0 i = 5
Thread 0 i = 6
Thread 0 i = 7
Thread 0 i = 8
Thread 0 i = 9
Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...
```

Comment: #pragma omp parallel и #pragma omp for лучше объединять, и стоит задавать кол-во потоков, например так - omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильная опция называется

```
 #Для C++
 QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS+=-fopenmp
 #Для C
 QMAKE_C_FLAGS+=-fopenmp
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос,  увы почему-то не заработало

Comment: @timob256 - не заметил, что вы пишете на C

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства "чтения" сего вопроса, выложу код текущий код.

Теперь **untopenm.pro** выглядит так:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

#QMAKE_LIBS+=-static -lpthread -fopenmp

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -fopenmp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp

SOURCES += main.c

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lomp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/
```

**main.c** не менялся .

вот вывод :

```
Thread 0 i = 0
Thread 0 i = 1
Thread 0 i = 2
Thread 0 i = 3
Thread 0 i = 4
Thread 1 i = 5
Thread 1 i = 6
Thread 1 i = 7
Thread 1 i = 8
Thread 1 i = 9
Для закрытия данного окна нажмите <ВВОД>...
```